# Fibonacci Series using classes and methods

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I have written a fibonacci series method and tried calling it. It works fine with the following code:

```
module Fibonacci
  class Operation
    def fibonacci(n)
      num1 = 0
      num2 = 1
      while num2 < n
        puts num2
        num1, num2 = num2, num1 + num2
      end
    end
end

  res = Operation.new
  puts 'Enter the number upto which Fibonacci needs to be printed:'
  n = gets.chomp.to_i
  res.fibonacci(n)
end
```

But I want to have a seperate method for accepting input within the class and calling it.

```
module Fibonacci
  class Operation
    def input
    puts 'Enter the number upto which Fibonacci needs to be printed:'
    n = gets.chomp.to_i
    end
    def fibonacci(n)
      num1 = 0
      num2 = 1
      while num2 < n
        puts num2
        num1, num2 = num2, num1 + num2
      end
    end
end

  res = Operation.new
  res.input
  res.fibonacci(n)
end
```

Getting an Error!..I'm a newbie, Would be helpful if I get a support..Thank You

Comment: "Getting an Error!" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, your code doesn't use the return value of your `input` function; it disappears into the ether, and your caller has an undefined `n` it's attempting to access. If you write your calling code as:

```
res = Operation.new
res.fibonacci(res.input)
```

Then you pass the return value from `res.input` into `res.fibonacci` and your immediate problem is resolved.

Beyond this, I believe there are noteworthy design issues in your code which you may consider. Functions should be modular and avoid [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) such as printing, which severely limit their usefulness and flexibility. What if you wish to generate Fibonacci numbers and use them for something else in your program? You have to rewrite the whole function again. If you write it once to populate and return an array, you let the caller decide whether to print the output, save it in a database, send it through a socket, reverse it, send it into another function (you get the idea).

Seek to avoid [hard-coded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) values like string and numbers. Your `input` function can't work for anything but collecting Fibonacci numbers. What if you let the caller decide what the message is? Then, when you add more math functions to your `Operation` class, you can reuse the same `input` routine.

I would also contend that a function like `input` doesn't belong in an `Operator` class. I can see it used as a utility function in that class, but it's independent of `Operator`-like stuff and is too small to warrant its own function in any case.

Here's a re-write that somewhat mitigates these issues:

```
module Fibonacci
  class Operation
    def input(message)
      puts message
      gets.chomp.to_i
    end

    def fibonacci(n)
      num1 = 0
      num2 = 1
      result = []
      
      while num2 < n
        result << num2
        num1, num2 = num2, num1 + num2
      end

      result
    end
  end

  res = Operation.new
  puts res.fibonacci(res.input 'Enter the number upto which Fibonacci needs to be printed:')
end
```

And a sample run:

```
Enter the number upto which Fibonacci needs to be printed:
 15
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
```

Answer (score 0):

Change code to:

```
def input
  puts 'Enter the number upto which Fibonacci needs to be printed:'
  n = gets.chomp.to_i
  fibonacci(n)
end
```

And remove `res.fibonacci(n)`.

Here is the full code:

```
module Fibonacci
  class Operation
    def input
    puts 'Enter the number upto which Fibonacci needs to be printed:'
    n = gets.chomp.to_i
    fibonacci(n)
    end

    def fibonacci(n)
      num1 = 0
      num2 = 1
      while num2 < n
        puts num2
        num1, num2 = num2, num1 + num2
      end
    end
end

  res = Operation.new
  res.input
end
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

It could incredibly help if you have specified *what exact error* do you have, but let me guess: it’s kinda “`NameError`: undefined local variable or method `n'”

That happens because you have not passed an argument in your call to `fibonacci`. You have an option to fallback to getting the variable from the user input if none was specified:

```
  class Operation
    def input
      puts 'Enter the number upto which Fibonacci needs to be printed:'
      gets.chomp.to_i
    end

    def fibonacci(n = -1)
      # HERE
      n = input if n <= 0

      num1 = 0
      num2 = 1
      while num2 < n
        puts num2
        num1, num2 = num2, num1 + num2
      end
    end
  end

  res = Operation.new
  res.fibonacci(5)
  #⇒ 1 1 2 3

  res.fibonacci
  #⇒ 'Enter the number ...'
```